# Why the series to the power of two differs from the expanded AR(2) equation?

Tags: time-series, convergence, autoregressive, distributed-lag

I am trying to rewrite the series $\tilde{R}_{t}=\beta_{2}\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{U_{t-s}}{\phi^{s+1}}\right)^{2}$ as an $AR(2)$ using lag operators $L$. I expand the series, define $\alpha=\frac{1}{\phi}$, where $\left|\alpha\right|<1$,  and use lag polynomials as follows:

$$
\tilde{R}_{t}=\beta_{2}\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{U_{t-s}}{\phi^{s+1}}\right)^{2} = \beta_{2}
\left[
\frac{1}{\phi}
\left(U_{t}+\frac{U_{t-1}}{\phi}+\frac{U_{t-2}}{\phi^2}+\frac{U_{t-3}}{\phi^3}+...
\right)
\right]^2 = 
\beta_{2}\left[\alpha\left(1-\alpha L\right)^{-1}U_{t}\right]^{2}=
\beta_{2}\alpha^{2}\left(1-\alpha L\right)^{-2}U_{t}^{2}
$$

Rearranging terms, I can rewrite the equation as an $AR(2)$:

$$
\left(1-\alpha L \right)^{2}\tilde{R}_{t} = \beta_{2}\alpha^{2}U_{t}^{2}
$$

$$
\left(1-2\alpha L+\alpha^{2}L^{2} \right)\tilde{R}_{t} = \beta_{2}\alpha^{2}U_{t}^{2}
$$

$$
\tilde{R}_{t} = 2\alpha\tilde{R}_{t-1} - \alpha^{2}\tilde{R}_{t-2}+\beta_{2}\alpha^{2}U_{t}^{2}
$$
However, if I try to simulate numerically the series and compare the initial version (the infinite sum to the power of two) with the last version (the expanded $AR(2)$ version), these two series do not numerically coincide except for values of $\alpha$ close to zero.

The linear version of the series, $\bar{R}_{t}=\beta_{1}\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{U_{t-s}}{\phi^{s+1}}\right)$, is numerically equivalent to an $AR(1)$ equation,
$
\bar{R}_{t} = \beta_{1}\alpha\left(1-\alpha L \right)^{-1}U_{t}=\alpha\bar{R}_{t-1}+\beta_{1}\alpha U_{t}
$, regardless of the value of $\alpha$ instead.

**Why does the series to the power of two differ from the expanded AR(2) equation? Am I making mistakes in the derivation? Or am I missing something on the convergence of series to the power of two? Or anything else?**

Comment: What justifies $\beta_{2}\left[\alpha\left(1-\alpha L\right)^{-1}U_{t}\right]^{2}=
\beta_{2}\alpha^{2}\left(1-\alpha L\right)^{-2}U_{t}^{2}$??

Comment: Nothing. Thanks for pointing it out. The lag operator should be applied to $U_{t}$ before exponentiation.